# No bootable device found on Lubuntu

Tags: boot, lubuntu

When I start my old computer which has Lubuntu 12.04 shows no bootable devices found. Computer was working fine couple of times after I have installed Lubuntu but now it does not start but asks to insert bootable devices.
P.S  In Boot priority order internal HDD is at first.
Please help

Comment: Does the drive show up in the BIOS "Boot Options" menu?

Comment: Yes it shows up

Answer (score -1):

You could use a live cd to check or repair the disk
http://gparted.org/download.php
if all is well you can try to repair the boot
https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/

Comment: When I insert a bootable device(say USB or DVD), it boots but when I install the operating system on my HDD and remove USB it asks for bootable device

Comment: insert gparted live cd to check the disk for errors

Comment: I checked. My HDD is completely fine

Comment: Maybe if it's a installation problem  you can fix with boot-repair https://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/